# Webbrowser control not firing events depending on hosting service

Tags: webbrowser-control

I have a service that launches a new process to execute steps against a webbrowser control. This is working fine for simple things such as Navigate, Click, HTML scraping etc. Where it breaks down is firing events such as "onmouseup"/"onmousedown" etc. When running in the service these events simply do not fire. Running the exe directly also does not work. When I exercise the exact same code through a unit test however it works perfectly fine. Also instead of launching a new process if I launch the assembly in a new AppDomain it also works fine however this causes the session data to be mixed so it is not a viable option.

Does anyone know why the events fire when launched from an AppDomain but not from it's own process?

Comment: Do you have an code you can post?

Comment: There's not really a single set of code that would capture this all. The bit that fails to execute: `(public void MouseDown()
        {
           _element.RaiseEvent("onmousedown");
        })`

_element is an HtmlElement